# Apache POI - Trying to change the accent colors with POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to change the accent colors in POI because we have the need to put some corporate identity design colors into the excel reports for different clients, so that the pivot tables and charts are based on that.

Have it tried like this:

```
    StylesTable st = workbook.getStylesSource();
    ThemesTable theme = st.getTheme();
    // get one of the accent colors -> work
    XSSFColor accent1 = theme.getThemeColor(4);
    // trying to set a new color -> doesn't work
    st.getTheme().getThemeColor(i).setARGBHex("ED7D31");
```

but without luck. Is there a way to achieve this?

An alternative way for me could also be to export a specific style als ".thmx" and import the style on report creation. But for this solution I've found no possibility with POI.

Hope anyone could help me. Thank you.

Comment: Does this help ? XSSFColor bright_orange = new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(rgb(237,125,49)));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ThemesTable](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/model/ThemesTable.html) provides `getThemeColor` method which returns a `XSSFColor` generated from the `theme*.xlm`. But this is a new generated `XSSFColor`. Changes on this do not have affect to color scheme in themes table and will not be stored in `theme*.xlm` while writing the workbook.

`ThemesTable` does not provide a `setThemeColor` method until now. So we need programming that method our self using the underlaying low level mehods of `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.*`.

Following works for me using current `apache poi 5.0.0`. It replaces the `RGB` color of `accent1` color scheme.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.ThemeElement;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTColorScheme;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTColor;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTSRgbColor;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

class ExcelSetThemeColor {

 static void setThemeColor(ThemesTable xssfTheme, int idx, XSSFColor color) throws Exception {
  Field _theme = ThemesTable.class.getDeclaredField("theme");
  _theme.setAccessible(true);
  ThemeDocument theme = (ThemeDocument)_theme.get(xssfTheme);
  CTColorScheme colorScheme = theme.getTheme().getThemeElements().getClrScheme();
  CTColor ctColor = CTColor.Factory.newInstance();
  CTSRgbColor rgbColor = ctColor.addNewSrgbClr();
  rgbColor.setVal(color.getRGB());
  switch (ThemeElement.byId(idx)) {
   case LT1: colorScheme.setLt1(ctColor); break;
   case DK1: colorScheme.setDk1(ctColor); break;
   case LT2: colorScheme.setLt2(ctColor); break;
   case DK2: colorScheme.setDk2(ctColor); break;
   case ACCENT1: colorScheme.setAccent1(ctColor); break;
   case ACCENT2: colorScheme.setAccent2(ctColor); break;
   case ACCENT3: colorScheme.setAccent3(ctColor); break;
   case ACCENT4: colorScheme.setAccent4(ctColor); break;
   case ACCENT5: colorScheme.setAccent5(ctColor); break;
   case ACCENT6: colorScheme.setAccent6(ctColor); break;
   case HLINK: colorScheme.setHlink(ctColor); break;
   case FOLHLINK: colorScheme.setFolHlink(ctColor); break;
   default: ;
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("./ExcelTemplate.xlsx"));

  StylesTable st = workbook.getStylesSource();
  ThemesTable theme = st.getTheme();
  // get one of the accent colors -> work
  XSSFColor accent1 = theme.getThemeColor(4);
System.out.println(accent1.getARGBHex());

  // trying to set a new color
  accent1.setARGBHex("ED7D31");

  setThemeColor(theme, 4, accent1);
System.out.println(st.getTheme().getThemeColor(4).getARGBHex());

 
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Will try that - but we will have to switch to the newest POI because we are stuck at 3.13 atm.